# JQuery find all elements with a class add their id to a coma separated list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title says I want to find all `li` tags inside an ordered list called `#selectable` with the class `.ui-selected` and add their id's to a string with each id separated by a comma.

Here's an example of what my html looks like:

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li id="1" class="ui-selected"><li>
    <li id="2"><li>
    <li id="3" class="ui-selected"><li>
    <li id="4"><li>
    <li id="5" class="ui-selected"><li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That's an ordered list

Comment: Also your list items aren't closed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var selectedIds = $('#selectable .ui-selected').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join(',');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3KU7q/)

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Nice One..!!

Answer (score 0):

Was working with my fiddle and couldn't figure out why my test array was returning 10 items in stead of 5. You are not closing your list items use `<li></li>` in stead of `<li><li>`.

Your source was missing a `/`.

I pushed them in an array and converted the array to a string with `toString()`

```
var listItems = [];
$('#selectable .ui-selected').each(function(){
    var theID = $(this).attr('id');
   listItems.push(theID);    
});

listItems = listItems.toString();
console.log(listItems);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h6G8H/4/